# How create a launcher to C terminal program?

Tags: c, winapi, launcher

In Unix we have .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=name
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "PATH;bash"'
Icon=image.ico
```

Does it exist also one mode in Win32?

Comment: A shortcut maybe? Or a simple shell script.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. What you're showing isn't generically Unix, but applies to a specific desktop manager in Linux. But what's the Win32 question? You can't run a win32 app unless you have Wine running or other Windows emulator.

Comment: I would run a C terminal program with double click under Windows, like i do in Linux with .deskop file.

Comment: @Paolovox you probably want a shortcut... but your question would be more suitable for a site like [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Is 'shortcut' synonymous of 'program launch icon'??